# Demonstration of magnetic field lines "tension" and "pressure" using the Maxwell stress tensor

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields, pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, forces

I would like to show that the magnetic fields lines are under "tension" along the lines and exert "pressure" perpendicularly to the lines, using the Maxwell tensor only.  I have a sign ambiguity.

In Special Relativity, the electromagnetic field stress-energy-momentum tensor is defined with these components (using cartesian coordinates in an inertial frame.  I'm using $c = 1$ and $\mu_0 = 1$ for simplicity.  Metric signature is the "mostly negative" : $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$):
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
T^{ab} = {F^a}_c \, F^{cb} + \frac{1}{4} \, \eta^{ab} \, F_{cd} \, F^{cd}.
\end{equation}
The Maxwell stress tensor is defined by the space part:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
T^{ij} = {F^i}_c \, F^{c j} - \frac{1}{4} \, \delta^{ij} \, F_{cd} \, F^{cd}.
\end{equation}
Explicitely, assuming a magnetic field only ($F_{0 i} = 0$ and $F_{ij} = -\, \varepsilon_{ijk} \, B_k$):
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
T_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \, B^2 \, \delta_{ij} - B_i \, B_j.
\end{equation}
Now, I introduce an unit vector $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{n}}$ oriented in the direction of the magnetic field : $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{B}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\mathrm{n}} = B$, and a unit vector $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}}$ perpendicular to the local field line: $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{B}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}} = 0$.  Contracting these vectors to the components (3) gives these (notice the index position and the sign change, because of the Minkowski metric, since $\eta_{ij} = -\, \delta_{ij}$):
\begin{align}\tag{4}
{T^i}_j \, n^j &= \frac{1}{2} \, B^2 \, n^i, &{T^i}_j \, u^j &= -\, \frac{1}{2} \, B^2 \, u^i, 
\end{align}
According to these equations, the eigenvalue associated to the eigenvector vector $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{n}}$ is the positive magnetic energy density ($\mathcal{U} = \frac{1}{2} \, B^2 > 0$), while it is negative for the eigenvector $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}}$:
\begin{align}\tag{5}
{T^i}_j \, n^j &= \mathcal{U} \, n^i, &{T^i}_j \, u^j &= -\, \mathcal{U} \, u^i,.
\end{align}
*Tension* should be a "negative pressure".  The sign difference between both eigenvalues shows that the magnetic field line is under tension in some direction and exert a "pressure" in the orthogonal direction.  But how can I show that "tension" (i.e *negative pressure*) is along the field line (i.e in the direction of vector $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{n}}$), and not in its perpendicular direction?  It is not clear that the two equations of (5) are telling that there is negative pressure (i.e *tension*) in the $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{n}}$ direction and positive pressure in the $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}}$ direction.  By lowering all the indices of these equations, I could also write these:
\begin{align}\tag{6}
T_{ij} \, n_j &= -\, \mathcal{U} \, n_i, &T_{ij} \, u_j &= +\, \mathcal{U} \, u_i.
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking. You already showed that the tensor has opposite sign in the $n$ and two independent $u$ directions. So are you just asking why the eigenvalue of $T^i_{\,\,j}$ has the interpretation as a negative pressure rather than positive?

Comment: @octonion, no, I'm asking what is the proper way to show that the field lines are in tension along themselves.  Tension is a negative pressure, but the first equation of (5) has a positive eigenvalue.  This equation alone isn't sufficient to show that it's actually representing a tension.

Comment: So although you said "no" it sounds like you just restated what I suspected your question was. Compare your result with the energy momentum tensor of a perfect fluid in the mostly negative signature. You will see that the sign you are getting is consistent with it being interpreted as a negative pressure.

Comment: @octonion, can you be more specific?  Can you offer a detailed answer to the question?  I don't see clearly how the Maxwell 3-tensor shows that the field lines are under tension, while exerting a transverse pressure.

Comment: @octonion, a prefect fluid is locally isotropic.  The space part of its energy-momentum is \begin{equation}T_{ij} = (\rho + p) \, \gamma^2 \, v_i \, v_j + p \, \delta_{ij}. \end{equation}  The Maxwell tensor (3) can be written as this:\begin{equation}T_{ij} = - 2 \, \mathcal{U} \, n_i \, n_j + \mathcal{U} \, \delta_{ij},\end{equation} and doesn't represent a kind of isotropic fluid.

Comment: I made the question clearer at the end of the last paragraph.

Comment: I am aware that MHD is not an isotropic fluid. In fact I have written papers on anisotropic fluids in general relativity like MHD, and am trying to help you. In your situation, your $v_i=0$ since you set $E=0$. So you can see that $p\delta_{ij}$ is positive just like the two components of $\mathcal{U}\delta_{ij}$ in the perpendicular directions. The direction $n_i n_j$ is negative.

Comment: @octonion, I may have found the proper interpretation.  In newtonian mechanics and using cartesian coordinates, there is no distinction between upper and lower indices.  As a rule of thumb, every index should be written in the lower position (so there is no confusion with signs from Minkowski's metric).  The fluid's pressure-tension force element applied on a small surface is given by the expression $dF_i = T_{ij} \, dS_j$.  If $dS_j = n_j \, dS$ is oriented in the direction of the magnetic field (like a "velocity field"), then (6) gives $dF_i = -\, \mathcal{U} n_i \, dS$, which is a tension.